# can i merge resolution with float single data type

Tags: erdas-imagine

Can I merge resolution with both image is float single data type?
I have done this, but the output image become white.
Do the data type must be in unsigned-8 bit for the merge to be success?

Answer (score 1):

I am having difficulty understanding the scenario. One solution, if I understand properly, would be to create a file geodatabase in ArcCatalog.  Create a mosaic dataset within the file geodatabase, and add rasters by right clicking on the mosaic dataset once created.  Here you will be able to set a pixel depth for all rasters being added... such as a 32 bit floating point or 8 bit signed.  You will want to determine the use first, as applying colormap functions require a 1, 4, 8, or 16 bit signed/ or unsigned integer.  You would want to use Signed Integer if you have negative values.  If you are just applying a slope or aspect function, 32-bit floating point will work properly, however once you run a function, you will have to recalculate statistics for the mosaic dataset by right clicking on the mosaic dataset> enchance tab> calculate statistics.